# How to echo a string with single quotes without backslash

Tags: php, mysql, web, echo, backslash

Here is my code

```
$user_data = "I'm awesome";
echo $user_data;
```

This for some reason echoes `I\'m awesome` in my site. I found this odd and weird. I put it in a variable because the value of this changes within the action of a function, searching through a MySQL Database. I cannot find the problem.
Please HELP!

Comment: You probably have magic quotes enabled. [Disable them](http://php.net/security.magicquotes.disabling).

Comment: Update your Webserver. magic quotes are deprecated since 5.3 and DISABLED since 5.4 - you have to have an old PHP version.

Comment: Possible duplicate [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522313/php-mysql-real-escape-string-stripslashes-leaving-multiple-slashes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `stripslashes()` function

```
$user_data = "I'm awesome";
$user_data = stripslashes($user_data);
echo $user_data;
```

Comment: 1 point to this: If stripslashes is NOT working for deleting backslashes, you probably have 'magic_quotes_sybase' activated. When it's activated, one backslash won't be removed, but two backslashes will be replaced with one.

Comment: Yeah I know, realized right after I posted the question! Can't delete it now, thanks anyways :D

Comment: Glad you have got it fixed. Hopefully this will help others that have the same problem in the future.