# MySQL returns data twice

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code, simplified heavily while trying to get to the bottom of this:

```
<?php
  $db_host   = $_ENV['DATABASE_SERVER'];
  $db_pass   = 'dummypassword';
  $db_user   = 'user';
  $db_name   = 'database';
  $db_char   = 'utf8';

  $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;charset=$db_char", $db_user, $db_pass);
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $email = 'david@example.com';

  if (!empty(trim($email)))
    {
      $sql = 'SELECT * FROM staff';
      $query = $db->prepare($sql);
      $query->execute();
      $results = $query->fetchAll();

      echo '<pre>';
      print_r($results);
      echo '</pre>';
    }
?>
```

When I run this, the query works fine and I get no errors. What I do get however is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [staff_id] => 1
            [0] => 1
            [staff_org] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [staff_email] => david@example.com
            [2] => david@example.com
            [staff_password] => hashyhashy
            [3] => hashyhashy
            [staff_first_name] => David
            [4] => David
            [staff_start_date] => 2014-03-17
            [7] => 2014-03-17
            [staff_leave_date] => 
            [8] => 
        )
)
```

Personally I don't remember ever seeing it return the data twice like this (i.e. with a named key, and then again without). My question is this... have I lost my mind and this always how results from MySQL have been returned? Or have I done something to make it do this?

Comment: Thats supposed to happen when you use the default `fetchAll()`. It allows you to use the array like `$results[0]` or `$results['staff_id;]` Use `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` for just the `$results['staff_id;]` version and `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM)` for just the `$results[0]` The default you see in yuur result is because the default is `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)`

Comment: look at this for inspiration http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31906248/user-inputs-clean-and-sanitize-before-sending-to-db/31996862#31996862

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting both a numeric zero-indexed key and an associative key. If you need just the associative array, you can do:

```
$results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

and if you just want numeric keys, you do:

```
$results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

Check the manual on [`fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) for more details.

Comment: Of course it is. Thanks! Nice and simple answer - amazing what a second pair of eyes does! That was doing my head in

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the optional parameter `fetch_style` to the `fetchAll()` method. The default value of this parameter is `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` so that the result array contains the numeric and the associative keys.

If you only want to get the associative array keys, you have to change

```
$query->fetchAll();
```

to

```
$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 2):

$query->fetchAll(); defaults to the PDO::FETCH_BOTH fetch style, which returns both the numbered array and the named array.

This should get you just the named array:

```
$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Refs:

[PHP Man page for fetch_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

[PHP Man page for fetch()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)