# Sending information to database SQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i have a form to send to table. there is two drop down list. first has information about job of current user that logged in and second one fetch all usernames of users. a field for date a field for price and a field for comment. so my code is here:

> this code get all information. submit.action.php

```
 <form name="form5" method="post" action="send_action.php" >


<div dir="rtl">         
                <?php

   $db_host = 'localhost';
   $db_name= 'site';
   $db_table= 'job_list';
   $db_user = 'root';
   $db_pass = '';

  $user=$fgmembersite->UserNameOfUser();

  $con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die("خطا در اتصال به پايگاه داده");
  $selected=mysql_select_db($db_name, $con) or die("خطا در انتخاب پايگاه داده");
 mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET  utf8");

 $dbresult=mysql_query("SELECT job_list.job_id,
                               job_list.job_name,
                       tablesite.username
                   FROM  $db_table
          INNER JOIN relation
          on job_list.job_id=relation.job_id
          INNER JOIN tablesite
          on relation.user_id=tablesite.id_user AND tablesite.username='$user'",$con);
 echo'* خدمتی که ارائه داده اید: ','<br/>';                    
 echo '<select name="job" dir="rtl">';

 while($amch=mysql_fetch_assoc($dbresult))
 {
 echo '<option value="'.$amch['job_id'].'">'.$amch['job_name'].'</option>';
 }
 echo '</select>'; ?><br/>
 </div>     
 <!--************************************************************** --> 
 <div dir="rtl">    
 <?php  
 $db_host = 'localhost';
 $db_name= 'site';
 $db_table2= 'tablesite';
 $db_user = 'root';
 $db_pass = '';

 $con2 = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die("خطا در اتصال به پايگاه داده");
 $selected=mysql_select_db($db_name, $con2) or die("خطا در انتخاب پايگاه داده");
 mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET  utf8");

 $dbresult=mysql_query("SELECT *
                              FROM  $db_table2",$con2);
 echo'* نام کاربری که به او خدمت داده اید: ','<br/>';                      
     echo '<select name="users" dir="rtl">';

     while($amch=mysql_fetch_assoc($dbresult))
      {
   echo '<option value="'.$amch['id_user'].'">'.$amch['username'].'</option>';
      }
   echo '</select>'; ?><br/>



   <label for='date' >* تاریخ عملیات:</label><br/>
   <input type='text' name='date' id='date' value='' maxlength="11" placeholder="1394/1/1" /><br/>
   <label for='price' >* هزینه کار:</label><br/>
   <input type='text'  dir="rtl" name='price' id='price' value='' maxlength="50" placeholder="54000"/><br/>

   <label for='textaria' >توضیحات:</label><br/>
   <textarea name="textaria" cols="" rows=""></textarea><br/>
   <input name="submit" type="submit" value="ثبت عملیات" />
   </div>
    </form>
  </span>
  </div>
```

and in this page we send information to database but nothing sends!:

```
 <?php
 require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>ارسال عملیات</title>
 </head>

 <body>

 <?php
 $id=$fgmembersite->UserID(); 
 echo "$id"; ?>

 <?php
 $db_host = 'localhost';
 $db_name= 'site';
 $db_table= 'action';
 $db_user = 'root';
 $db_pass = '';


 $con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die("خطا در اتصال به پايگاه داده");

 mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $con);
 mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'", $con);
 mysql_query("SET character_set_connection = 'utf8'", $con);


 $selected=mysql_select_db($db_name, $con) or die("خطا در انتخاب پايگاه داده");
 $ins = "INSERT INTO $db_table
     (service_provider_id,customer_id,date,price,job_id,service_provider_comment)
     VALUES ('$id',
             '" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['users']) . "',
             '" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['date']) . "',
             '" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['price']) . "',
             '" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['job']) . "',
             '" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['textaria']) . "')";
$saved=mysql_query($ins );
mysql_close($con); 

?>

</body>
</html>
```

> note: above code give all value of dropdown list and text boxes and textarea and should send them to databasetable.
>
> note: fg_membersite included by:

```
      function UserID()
    {
          return isset($_SESSION['user_id'])?$_SESSION['user_id']:'';
    }
```

my table is as this:

```
    job_id                   int(11)
    service_provider_id      int(10)
    customer_id              int(10)
    date                     int(50)
    price                    int(255)
    vote                     varchar(255)
    service_provider_comment varchar(255)
    customer_comment         varchar(255)
```

Comment: Your code may contain syntax errors. 
Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- no error is there! code is true? need to write table entities too?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have also error, this is because OP using old supported system, neither mine nor yours environment are compatible longer, I think it is because some components of the code are deprecated. ;) any I will take a look and see what I can do.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ: u always helped me bro... i think realy i must not use of sql anymore.

Comment: One thing to note is that you have a field named `date` which has special meaning - thus you ought to encase fields names in backticks..

Comment: @RamRaider: im in basic level of puting information to table, in this level date is a simple field and do not have any special codes...

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ: did u found the problem?

Comment: @sajad right now i am in work doing other stuff, but check it later ;) you got my word

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ: thanks :)

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ: i need your help, are you online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Introduction

After looking around in your code, I have debugged your code and have localized the problem. And there are few puzzles in the problem.

I have in my test environment created your code scenario.

Your main form posts the submitted content over to `send_action.php`.

### The problem

For debugging, I have in `send_action.php` page and after `$selected = ....` line added `var_dump($_POST);`. This is see where ever if the submitted content is received at all?

It shows that Job is for some reason is not posted and your `($_POST['job'])` with error message `Undefined index` and since this error happens inside your `INSERT` statement. Therefore nothing get inserted.

### The solution

I have checked Job and it was empty, I have added a option called default value echo `'<option value="0">default job</option>';`, this is to ensure if your job list is empty under testing environment then some thing should be submitted otherwise it will returns null and gives you the problem.

```
echo '<select name="job">';
echo '<option value="0">default job</option>';
while ($amch = mysql_fetch_assoc($dbresult))
{
    echo '<option value="' . $amch['job_id'] . '">' . $amch['job_name'] . '</option>';
}
```

So far so good.

I have tested injecting manually data in your insert method and it works fine.

### Finally:

After putting default value in job now every thing is working fine and your form is submitting and saving to database.

### Conclusion

1. It is important to switch over to MySQLi or PDO
2. Variable naming should be improved
3. Make use of function to reducing mass repetitive codes like `mysql_escape_string` or database connection, make central page and include the connection (I have an answer showing a min project using PDO you can take a look and get inspiration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31906248/user-inputs-clean-and-sanitize-before-sending-to-db/31996862#31996862))
4. Better and more clear code and data structure.

### Note

The solution is based on what is presented in your code as is, I have had no chance to test in depth or against a final running database. I have created a table for inserting the data, I have also got your old version database var_dump which helped also.

Comment: oh that did not worked :( may problem related to my table? let me add my table to question.

Comment: i got where is problem. when i create relation in table, form returns null, i have two primary keys. but when i remove relation that works property!

Comment: Again @sajad as you can see every thing in web development is depending on each other, clean code, better structure, good var names and good database design will play a role at the final end, there will always be small problems and challenges but those will got reduced doing all that better. any way I understand that you are in your beginner phase, that is fare, but try to improve, what suggested. Good luck.

Comment: im happy becuase you help me always and i think i can improve my coding with your help and others :) thanks bro :)

Comment: i think just you can help me here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33550554/insert-to-all-cells-when-records-are-more-than-one-php